# Single row with optional data from multiple other rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which has multiple entries with the same `key`. What I need to do is pull back a single row which has all of the `column` information for each row which has the same `key`.

I've tried searching for help with this online, but I can't figure out which search terms will get me a useful result. So - I've tried the solution below - but I don't think it's the best - and I'm looking for advice on how to improve it.

**Update:**

As an example, all of the rows have some columns which are *required* (non-null), but there are 3 columns in specific which *are not required* (nullable) - namely `info1`, `otherinfo` and `lastinfo`.

So - I want to pull back a single row which contains all *required* columns from each of the rows.

Assume that:

- Row 2 has all of the *required* columns set, as well as data for `info1`, and
- Row 3 has all *required* columns set - but none of the *non-required* fields have data. This means row 3 should be skipped.
- Row 4 has all *required* columns set - as well as data for `info1`, `otherinfo` and `lastinfo`

What I want to return, in this case, is the *required* data from row 1, `info1` from row 2, nothing from row 3, and `otherinfo` and `lastinfo` for row 4 (skipping `info1` because it was already set by row 2).

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       IFNULL(a.info1, IFNULL(b.info1, IFNULL(c.info1, null))) AS info1
     , IFNULL(a.otherinfo, IFNULL(b.otherinfo, IFNULL(c.otherinfo, null))) AS otherinfo
     , IFNULL(a.lastinfo, IFNULL(b.lastinfo, IFNULL(c.lastinfo, null))) AS lastinfo
FROM entries a 
LEFT JOIN entries b ON (
    a.key = b.key && (
        (a.info1 IS NULL && b.info1 IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.otherinfo IS NULL && b.otherinfo IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.lastinfo IS NULL && b.lastinfo IS NOT NULL)
    )
)
LEFT JOIN entries c ON (
    a.key = c.key && (
        (a.info1 IS NULL && c.info1 IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.otherinfo IS NULL && c.otherinfo IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.lastinfo IS NULL && c.lastinfo IS NOT NULL)
    )
)
LEFT JOIN entries d ON (
    a.key = d.key && (
        (a.info1 IS NULL && d.info1 IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.otherinfo IS NULL && d.otherinfo IS NOT NULL) ||
        (a.lastinfo IS NULL && d.lastinfo IS NOT NULL)
    )
)
WHERE a.key = @_id
ORDER BY a.createdate DESC, 
         b.createdate DESC, 
         c.createdate DESC, 
         d.createdate DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

**Update:** Solved it with the following code:

```
SELECT e.*, 
       e2.info1 AS info1, 
       e3.otherinfo AS otherinfo, 
       e4.lastinfo AS lastinfo 
FROM entries AS e 
LEFT JOIN entries AS e2 ON (
    e.key = e2.key && (e.info1 is null && e2.info1 IS NOT NULL)
)
LEFT JOIN entries AS e3 ON (
    e.key = e3.key && (e.otherinfo is null && e3.otherinfo IS NOT NULL)
) 
LEFT JOIN entries AS e4 ON (
    e.key = e4.key && (e.lastinfo IS NULL && e4.lastinfo IS NOT NULL)
) 
WHERE e.key = @_id 
ORDER BY e.createdate DESC, 
         e2.createdate DESC, 
         e3.createdate DESC, 
         e4.createdate DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Update your question by *appending* your table schema and sample data please. It helps us to help you :)

Comment: Ok.. I found my own solution.

For all who interested in..:

    SELECT e.*, e2.info1 as info1, e3.otherinfo as otherinfo, e4.lastinfo as lastinfo
  FROM entries as e
   LEFT JOIN entries AS e2 ON (e.key = e2.key
      && (e.info1 is null && e2.info1 is not null))
   LEFT JOIN entries AS e3 ON (e.key = e3.key
      && (e.otherinfo is null && e3.otherinfo is not null))
   LEFT JOIN entries AS e4 ON (e.key = e4.key
      && (e.lastinfo is null && e4.lastinfo is not null))
  WHERE e.key = @_id
  order by e.createdate DESC, e2.createdate DESC, e3.createdate DESC, e4.createdate DESC
  LIMIT 1;

Comment: ps: stupid rule, not to answer your questions for 8 hours for new users..

Comment: Updated your original question with your answer, for future users to refer to.

Comment: @user1929711 the rule is to prevent new users from rapidly gaining reputation points which translate into site privileges that must be earned. But please do come back and post your answer when the timeout expires.